# Strapi 'EROFS: read-only file system' error after deploying to Google App Engine (GCP)

Tags: strapi

After running `gcloud app deploy` (which I've successfully run before), I'm now not able to start my Strapi server properly. If I try to access /admin I get a 500 error and if I monitor the logs with `gcloud app logs tail -s default` I get the following:

```
2020-11-10 15:16:52 default[20201110t151110]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 204
2020-11-10 15:25:47 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/settings/webhooks HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:25:47 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:47.357Z] debug GET webhooks (6 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:25:47 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/main.e0941b93.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:25:47 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/runtime~main.9c90e73e.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:25:47 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:47.426Z] debug GET runtime~main.9c90e73e.js (6 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:25:47 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:47.449Z] debug GET main.e0941b93.chunk.js (12 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /users-permissions/init HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 204
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:49.237Z] debug GET /users-permissions/init (204 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/init HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:49.288Z] debug GET /admin/init (3 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /content-manager/content-types HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:49.369Z] debug GET /content-manager/content-types (23 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /content-manager/content-types HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:49.432Z] debug GET /content-manager/content-types (25 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/webhooks HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/cc1d824d8f006f0a47c72638f4ce0376.png HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/e631d2735799aa943d93d301abf423d2.ttf HTTP/1.1" 500
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/57d69e1d4ce0cc10ace9264b4af92cf1.ttf HTTP/1.1" 500
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/2d36b1a925432bae7f3c53a340868c6e.ttf HTTP/1.1" 500
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/85d339d916479f729938d2911b85bf1f.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:49.581Z] debug GET cc1d824d8f006f0a47c72638f4ce0376.png (6 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:49.612Z] debug GET /admin/webhooks (43 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:49.658Z] debug GET 85d339d916479f729938d2911b85bf1f.ttf (43 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/55071ae1abc18726e23174192ebc0b68.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:25:49 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:49.743Z] debug GET 55071ae1abc18726e23174192ebc0b68.woff2 (10 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:58.401Z] debug ?? Server wasn't able to start properly.
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:58.402Z] debug ?? Server wasn't able to start properly.
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:58.404Z] error error: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Parser.handlePacket (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Parser.parse (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Socket.stream.on (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:8:42)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:58.406Z] error error: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Parser.handlePacket (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Parser.parse (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Socket.stream.on (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:8:42)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Pipe.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:58.418Z] debug ?? Server wasn't able to start properly.
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:25:58.420Z] error error: sorry, too many clients already :: proc.c:364
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Parser.handlePacket (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Parser.parse (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Socket.stream.on (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:8:42)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
2020-11-10 15:25:58 default[20200930t185305]      at Pipe.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
2020-11-10 15:39:29 default[20201110t153157]  "GET /admin/settings/webhooks HTTP/1.1" 500
2020-11-10 15:39:33 default[20201110t153157]  Error while running command start: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/workspace/.strapi-updater.json.1249708791'
2020-11-10 15:39:34 default[20201110t153157]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 204
2020-11-10 15:43:34 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/settings/webhooks HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]   Project information
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  ? Time               ? Tue Nov 10 2020 15:43:41 GMT+0000 (Coordinated ? ?
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  ? Launched in        ? 4366 ms                                          ?
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  ? Environment        ? production                                       ?
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  ? Process PID        ? 10                                               ?
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  ? Version            ? 3.0.1 (node v10.22.1)                            ?
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]   Actions available
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  Welcome back!
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  To manage your project ?, go to the administration panel at:
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  http://0.0.0.0:8081/admin
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  To access the server ??, go to:
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  http://0.0.0.0:8081
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]
2020-11-10 15:43:41 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:43:41.906Z] debug GET webhooks (73 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:43:42 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/main.e0941b93.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2020-11-10 15:43:42 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /admin/runtime~main.9c90e73e.js HTTP/1.1" 500
2020-11-10 15:43:42 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:43:42.048Z] debug GET main.e0941b93.chunk.js (7 ms) 200
2020-11-10 15:43:48 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:43:48.275Z] debug ?? Server wasn't able to start properly.
2020-11-10 15:43:48 default[20200930t185305]  [2020-11-10T15:43:48.277Z] error error: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
2020-11-10 15:43:48 default[20200930t185305]      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
2020-11-10 15:43:48 default[20200930t185305]      at Parser.handlePacket (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2020-11-10 15:43:48 default[20200930t185305]      at Parser.parse (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2020-11-10 15:43:48 default[20200930t185305]      at Socket.stream.on (/workspace/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:8:42)
2020-11-10 15:43:48 default[20200930t185305]      at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
2020-11-10 15:43:48 default[20200930t185305]      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
2020-11-10 15:43:48 default[20200930t185305]      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
2020-11-10 15:43:48 default[20200930t185305]      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
2020-11-10 15:43:48 default[20200930t185305]      at Pipe.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
2020-11-10 15:43:48 default[20200930t185305]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 204
2020-11-10 15:48:31 default[20201110t154254]  "POST /auth/local/register HTTP/1.1" 500
2020-11-10 15:48:37 default[20201110t154254]  Error while running command start: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/workspace/.strapi-updater.json.2714151597'
2020-11-10 15:48:41 default[20201110t154254]  "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500
```

I can see some mention of 'connection slots' but on checking my SQL server status I can see that there aren't too many connections - this is a test server after all.

I can also see the 'EROFS: read-only file system' error which suggests that Strapi is trying to write to the disk. However, I can't understand why this would've changed since I last deployed. I've even tried rolling back to the last version (which was working) and deploying that one, but still no luck!

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

As usually happens, I fix my own issue before anyone else can answer :)

I was able to downgrade to Strapi v3.2.4 by following the instructions here: https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/update-version.html#upgrade-your-dependencies

After following all of those steps and running `gcloud app deploy` again, everything worked!